# Boost.Python returning by internal reference

Tags: boost-python

Given two classes:

```
class B {
  // ...
};

class A {
 public:
  B& b() { return *b_; }
 private:
  B* b_;
};
```

In the Boost.Python module, I have

```
bp::class_<B, boost::noncopyable>(...)...;
```

which works fine.  I also have

```
bp::class_<A, boost::noncopyable>(...)
  .def("b", &A::b,
       bp::return_internal_reference<>()
      )
```

but it doesn't compile.  It says:

```
/opt/local/include/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:102:109: error: 'struct boost::python::detail::reference_existing_object_requires_a_pointer_or_reference_return_type<B>' has no member named 'get_pytype'
```

But, it should have a pytype, right?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with this code, it compiles fine. (boost 1.47, gcc 4.2.1, python 2.7.1)

Comment: I'm no longer working on this, but this was gcc 4.5, python 3.1 I think.

Comment: I second James - can't reproduce it either.

Comment: @AndréAnjos: Thank you for looking into this.  This is a couple years old and it might have been fixed.  I'll delete the question in a few minutes.